# is there a php function to return the difference between any 2 integer numbers as a positive integer?

Tags: php

I have googled, yahooed and researched SO but no luck.  I am trying to compare 2 numbers using **PHP**.

To be clear I know I can accomplish this using basic maths and maybe a simple

```
if{}
```

I know how to do this, I could write a simple function, finding the result but this is not my question.

My question is simply  - Is there a **PHP** function to return the difference between 2 integer numbers, +ve or -ve presented in any order as a positive integer

Example

```
PHPFunction(3,-2) result 5
```

Thanks

Comment: `abs(num1 - num2)` returns the difference between two numbers.

Comment: @Phylogenesis excellent thanks

Comment: Seriously why 5 downvotes - stated research, gave desired result. Google search on 'php function for difference between 2 numbers' shows 'http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php' with number abs ( mixed $number ) and echo abs(-4.2); - SO 'Difference between two number values where itemname is the same' - no mention of abs()

Comment: From stack exchange - Anonymously down voting without comment is as unhelpful as it is spineless. – OtagoHarbour

Comment: why couldn't you just use maths? like `$var = -1 - -2;` or `$var = 3 - 1;`. `abs()` will always return an absolute value so `$var = abs(1 - 3);` will return 2 while `$var = 1 - 3;` returns -2

Comment: @Memor-X 1 Thanks for the advice, but the abs() was exactly what I was looking for.  For my purposes the difference between 1 and 3 is 2 not -2

Comment: @kerry well you don't indicate that at all in your question. all 3 examples in your question using basic maths (and not using `abs`) produce those exact answers so the use of `abs` in those is entirely pointless in them, if you indicate that the answer has to always be positive then maybe the question wont read like *"how do i subtract one number from another"* which with your examples is how it reads because none of them need `abs`

Comment: i also hope that some comments have been deleted otherwise i am saddened that people jump at using a function like `abs` for [3 examples that don't need it](https://repl.it/Dtuz)

Comment: @Memor-X Thanks for pointing that out - I did not realise until I read it again.  I should have gived a better example - my apologies

Comment: I have edited the question after @Memor-X pointed out my error, to make it more useful to others

Comment: @Memor-X I can't talk for others, but it was *quite clear to me* what the actual intent of the question was, even if all three examples originally had num1 > num2. That is why I suggested using `abs()`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As pointed out by @Phylogenesis, you can use the [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function. For example:

```
$var1 = -30;
$var2 = -2;

echo abs($var1 - $var2); // 28
```

You could also define your own function:

```
function abs_diff($v1, $v2) {
    $diff = $v1 - $v2;
    return $diff < 0 ? (-1) * $diff : $diff;
}

echo abs_diff(-30, -2); // 28
```

Comment: sorry to be a pain but any idea why this will not work - UPDATE matchstats SET posspread = abs(homepos, awaypos)

Comment: You can post a new question for that. I would gladly help.

Comment: @kerry, well you're not totally banned. You can read more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Anyway sussed it out myself - I am confusing php abs with mysql abs - need to use the function in php not SQL - posting this comment as it may help others - thanks again for your help with original question - much appreciated

Comment: @kerry That's the spirit. Just keep going on, don't easily surrender tackling irritating problems. You'll get used to it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Use the absolute value function of php of the difference of the two numbers.

```
$answer = abs($num1 - $num2);
```

Comment: Just going through old posts, still amazed at the downvotes, asked a straightforward question and Phylogenesis and Rax Weber gave straightforward answers instead of suggesting other ways. If I google this now mine is the top entry - at least it may help others basically - yes there is a php function - abs($num1 - $num2); - thanks to those who helped me and will help others thanks to my question and their answers

Comment: @kerry, Agreed, Your question was and is valid and legit. There is a reason why we call some people idiots... Do your best. Good day.

Comment: @Gammer - thanks mate - you are the type of person forums like this need!

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting one number from another may not be the answer.

Measuring the *distance* between `1` and `-1` **(not subtraction)** is `2`?

`-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3`   How far apart are `1` and `-1`? The distance is `1` if zero is not a number or `2` if it is.

```
$var1 = -2;
$var2 = -30;

echo abs($var1 - $var2); // 28
```

Yes the result is `28` but the distance between `$var1` and `$var2` is `2`. Math function for distance?

Comment: I think you are wrong, substraction is indeed the way to calculate distance. Also the distance between `$var1` and `$var2` is not 2 but 28, which was correktly calculated by `abs(-30 - ( -2)) = 28`