# Difference of few numbers should be ignored

Tags: php, operators

I have two variables (Sum of calculated amount)

```
$total  = 100;
$total2 = 101;
```

I want to ignore this difference because its very minor and it should be working when I add if condition

```
    if($total == $total2){
         //condition if equal
    }else{
        //condition if not equal
    }
```

I want to ignore the difference of 10, if it is less 10 or greater 10. Is there any simple way to do it? or any php function that may help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a php function to return the difference between any 2 integer numbers as a positive integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972787/is-there-a-php-function-to-return-the-difference-between-any-2-integer-numbers-a)

Comment: Not really, because I am looking for solution with lesser code. I can code conditions to achieve this but I am looking if their is some php function already available that does it?

Comment: What you want was answered years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the test just needs to be a little more complex.

Get the difference as an integer, and amend the test to allow a difference of 10 or less.

```
if ( abs($total - $total2) < 11 ) {
```

or if you prefer

```
if ( abs($total - $total2) <= 10 ) {
```

Comment: Not really sure why this deserved a downvote :) Would someone like to explain please

Comment: This is the most concise solution, which the questioner, Akaash K, has asked for. Should be marked at the answer.